# Неточное сравнение чисел со строками в PHP

Tags: php

Есть несколько выражений:

```
1. var_dump("10" == "10");     #bool(true)
2. var_dump("10" == "0b1010"); #bool(false)
3. var_dump("10" == "0xA");    #bool(true)
4. var_dump("10" == "012");    #bool(false)
```

Только в двух вариантах функция `var_dump` выведет `bool(true)`, почему? Ведь в мануале про сравнение типов четко написано:

> В случае, если вы сравниваете число со строкой или две строки,
>   содержащие числа, каждая строка будет преобразована в число, и
>   сравниваться они будут как числа.

Получается там где `var_dump` выводит `false` он некорректно понимает тип данных? И с чем это связано?

Comment: Потому что вы везде строки сравниваете, а не разнотипные переменные.

Comment: @Visman вы цитату из мана видели?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"10" != "012" && "10" != "0b1010"
```

А ведь дело в правилах которые применяются к строкам.

Потому что в первом случае, PHP приводит строковый тип к Integer и получается что сравнивается 10 и 12, он в строках не понимает что вы подставляете ему восьмеричное число.

Во втором случае аналогичная ситуация в "0b1010", но там разбираться при строках ничего не будет. Один из операторов должен быть числом. Здесь при приведении типа строки "0b1010" к INTEGER она будет равна 0, а если бы было 1b1010 был бы равен 1, т.к. PHP когда приводит строку берет первые цифровые значения до первого символа отличного от цифр.

```
var_dump("0b1010" == "0"); //false
var_dump("0b1010" == 0); //true
var_dump("1b1010" == 1); //true
echo (int) "1b1010" // 1
echo (int) "0b1010" // 0
```

Для интерпретатора это остается строкой, за счет наличия там символа b, такая же ситуация будет с "0x10" в **PHP7!** В ранних версиях PHP строка с 0x10 будет автоматический приводится при сравнении к числу, за счет наличия такого правила. Потом это правило решили видимо убрать (но для 0b* его вообще не было)

**PHP 5.6**

```
var_dump("10" == "0xA"); //true
```

**PHP 7**

```
var_dump("10" == "0xA"); //false
```

Данное исправление утверждено в PHP7 [Removal of Hex Support in Numerical Strings](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_hex_support_in_numeric_strings)

**Если хотите точно сравнивать значение, не используйте строки, когда тип переменной ей не соответствует.**

Comment: да я знаю как строки преобразуются, мне было интересно только одно: почему шестнадцатеричную запись он понимает как число а вот восьмиричную и двоичную нет

Comment: Как видите в последней версии и шестнадцатеричную он тоже не понимает, видимо на то были причины отключить это при сравнении каких строк в определенных кейсах.

Answer (score 4):

```
intval("012"); // 12
intval("0b1010"); // 0
```

[Подробнее](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) о преобразовании строки в число в PHP (и еще в [документации intval](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.intval.php)).

Comment: Но `intval(0b1010); //10`

Comment: Да, но вы ведь сравниваете строку "0b1010", которая будет преобразовано в число.

Comment: Нет, я вам не возражал, я просто хотел обратить внимание читателей на разницу)

Comment: Вот, кстати, в официальной документации ни слова про то, почему "0b101"воспринимается как десятичный 0+строка "b101", "012" как десятичное 12, "0xA" как шеснадцатеричное 10.

Comment: @rjhdby именно поэтому я и задавал вопрос